# Cannot resolve method addWaypoint(com.mapbox.geojson.Point)

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation, mapbox, mapbox-android

I'm trying to put some waypoints on the Navigation UI but I have the issue of the title, here's my code, in the foreach is where I have the problem. It seems like I didn't import something

```
Point[] waypoints = {Point.fromLngLat(2.444740599999932, 41.5381124),Point.fromLngLat(2.407215469098446, 41.520481047202615};

      @Override
public void onNavigationReady() {
    NavigationViewOptions.Builder options = NavigationViewOptions.builder();
    options.navigationListener(this);
    options.origin(origin);
    options.destination(destination);
    options.shouldSimulateRoute(true);
    options.progressChangeListener(this);

    for (Point waypoint : waypoints) {
        options.addWaypoint(waypoint);
    }

    navigationView.startNavigation(options.build());
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain more precisely what the issue with your title is?

Comment: @Nathan I just can't use the function, as if I hadn't imported something

Comment: Do you miss anything on this?. Because "addWayPoint" is a method in NavigationRoute.Builder not NavigationViewOptions.Builder like you use.

Comment: @sontruongit So I should use navigation UI using NavigationRoute.Builder?

Comment: @Lluís yeah based on your requirement. You can take a look example code here: https://www.mapbox.com/help/android-navigation-sdk/

Comment: @sontruongit I'll look again, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***addWayPoint*** is a method from **NavigationRoute.Builder** not **NavigationViewOptions.Builder**. That why the IDE cannot resolve it.

From your code I guess you want to draw or simulate a navigation route (origin, destination, all points on route, etc..).

Please take a look examples at below official site how to use **NavigationRoute.Builder** API.

https://www.mapbox.com/help/android-navigation-sdk/